# Grunt task does not display proper value

Tags: gruntjs, typescript

I have create one grunt task. Below is code.

```
grunt.initConfig({
  log: {
    foo: [1, 2, 3],
    bar: 'hello world',
    baz: false
  }
});

grunt.registerMultiTask('log', 'Log stuff.', function() {
  grunt.log.writeln(this.target + ': ' + this.data);
});
```

Task is running fine. PFB screen shot.

[image]

this.target and this.data are displing "**undefined**". why it is showing undefined. Please let me know what i was missing.
Thanks.

**EDIT**- While debugged on grunt task, I have put break point inside of task. this.target and this.data are showing not valid property.

Comment: Are you in the same folder as the Gruntfile?  What happens if you add a default task that runs `log`, then just run the default?

Comment: Are you implying that your code is wrapped by `export function (grunt) {`? If so, just check that your `.ts` file is recompiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested the following and it works fine:

```
var grunt = require('grunt');

grunt.initConfig({
  log: {
    foo: [1, 2, 3],
    bar: 'hello world',
    baz: false
  }
});

grunt.registerMultiTask('log', 'Log stuff.', function() {
  grunt.log.writeln(this.target + ': ' + this.data);
});
```

As shown:

[image]

## Suggestions

- Use `require('grunt')`
- make sure you have latest `npm install grunt --save`
- Make sure you have latest `npm install grunt-cli -g`

## More Info

Here are my version numbers:

[image]

Comment: I have done all thing as you suggested but still it is showing undefined.

Comment: I've added my version numbers in more info. Give `npm install grunt-cli@0.1.13 -g` a go ;)

Comment: I am using grunt version 0.4.5 . let me try with 0.1.13.. . I have tried this  but still showing undefined.